# Bootable Antivirus software suite for windows OS (can be linux based)

Tags: antivirus

Is there any [preferably] bootable software suites that help to clean computers in one go, or are bundles of programs?

My first thought on this topic was to find Linux based live CD with required software - maybe there is some kind of distribution specialized in it?

- Software must be designed to fix problems with Windows based computers
- Have to be either bootable live CD or DOS tools.

What I'm looking for exactly: to have/create an USB/CD that would allow me to go from one station to another and start maintenance of computers (AV checks + preferably defragmentation of HDD, registry, MFT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would believe you look no further than [Hiren Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd). The website will inform you of all the tools you can use, which are compressed within a zip file, extracted to the PC at TEMP when used.

The tools also have a virtual window's tool, password remover, hardware testing etc. and are all in about a 1.92GB ISO file (downloaded from the site or via P2P torrent sites).

Some screenshots of the program are as follows:

[image: Hiren Menu]

In the later builds of Hiren they have refined their tools to be able to receive updates, crack Window's and add in a plethora of other tools you can use to run a system clean.

I believe this will cover everything you have requested.

Comment: But ain't Hiren a bit outdated? Site states last post was 2012... 2-3 years ago.

Comment: @Gacek Yes, the software build is outdated, but as discussed the software can be run/managed as you use it. The only items that really need to be updated are the virus databases too.

Comment: Does it take care of UKash viruses also? (except when encrypted)

Comment: @Gacek I cannot confirm to 100% that it does, I'd assume so. It has numerous virus scanners. On top of this you can also boot to a virtual Operating System, thus making the removal of virus' easier. You'd probably be best to see if any of the AV in the photo sport this ability; I'd assume ComboFix would.

Comment: OK. One more qeustion... I assume i can make it on bootable usb stick. Can I install/add programs to it?

Comment: @Gacek Yes, you can make it bootable. Being an open project, legally yes. I do believe so (there was some tool that came with a build for this).  I will double check and get back to you!

Comment: @Gacek I have found the method I was referring to: http://reboot.pro/topic/16160-hirens-boot-cd-customization/ If my answer was correct please mark it so :)

Comment: Think it's best one so far. Hoped to find something else than Hiren's. But it still is answer to question! Thx

Answer (score 2):

you can try Antivirus Live CD, a Linux distribution target to run ClamAV from the bootable CD. You can get it on SourceForge : http://sourceforge.net/projects/antiviruslivecd/

Comment: Thank you. Hiren got clamav built in and updateable also.