# What is a good free/open source virus/malware/etc. scanner for use on a Linux server, which also checks for Windows threats?

Tags: security, web-server, antivirus

Since it is a server whose visitors will likely be Windows based clients, the antivirus should also check for Windows threats (in addition to checking for threats to the server itself)?

In particular, the **needs** are:

- The primary use case is to scan files (uploaded by users) on an ad hoc basis by calling from a terminal/script.
- Linux based
- Terminal mode is necessary, so it can be run via scripts
- GUI doesn't matter
- able to detect a comprehensive range of malware -
- able to detect malware for Windows, OS X, as well as Linux

Other **nice to have** aspects (because there are other tools for these anyway):

- live background scans
- check text input/submissions for script attacks - both cross site xss, as well as DB injections
- use in conjunction with mail server, web server, file server.

Comment: Overlapping: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/bootable-antivirus-software-suite-for-windows-os-can-be-linux-based

Comment: @JanDoggen sorry, I must disagree, that question is asking about bootable AV for Windows which _can be_ Linux based. This question is about a Linux based AV software which also scans for Windows threats. Also, the accepted answer is completely irrelevant to this question.

Comment: OK, Yogesh – so let's kill those comments :) And as said below: ClamAV is what I'd recommend as well. Good maintained, regular updates, available in the repos of most Linux systems. Did a good job for years on my servers (and still does).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I have a good impression of clam on Linux systems too, but had no idea how it worked for servers. But I have also had a good experience with Avast, pity its no longer maintained for Linux..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/index.html) would probably do the trick for you.

I haven't personally used it for Linux, but it's worked well for me on Windows.

It's available for Linux and many others - you can even build from source if you like. It's also available as a package on many distributions.

It does have command line control, so scripting should be no problem.

I can't really speak to the breadth of it's signature database, but you can go to the website and look through the VirusDB mailing list archives.

There are many associated tools (for mailer integration, etc) on the website.

Comment: Beat me to it. My bad I've asked first for clarification :) Yes, and you might include with your answer: *ClamAV* is used with mail-servers for scanning mails, including `.doc` and `.exe` files in attachments. *Amavis* uses this on many installations. So I'd call it reliable (using it myself that way).